# ubuntu cannot display all the unicode

Tags: unity, unicode

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with default unity desktop, however it seems that it cannot display some of the unicode. e.g. U+1F648 the "see-no-evil" monkey. and it appears to be a white block in my browser and all text editor.
I was wondering that whether I need to install some package? Thanks.

Comment: run this `locale` in terminal and comment the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please install the "**ttf-ancient-fonts**" package.

You can do this in your terminal with `sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts`

After that you will be able to test this in python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u"\U0001F648"
```

Also, you will see this mokey here in this page.

Have fun!

Reference: http://dreamerc.blogspot.tw/2013/10/the-fates-and-monkeys.html

Comment: thx! i can see the monkey in this page and also in terminal...but i cannot in the link given  [link](http://dreamerc.blogspot.tw/2013/10/the-fates-and-monkeys.html) ,it appears to be white question mark in black rhombus.

Comment: Me too. I guess it's the coding of that page, I think it's fine since it works here.

Comment: Interestingly, there's no need to even restart Firefox — it works on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your locale:

run `locale` in terminal

suppose you get output like:

```
LANG=en_US
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

you can have different value other than this `en_US`

type this `sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

dont forget to replace `en_US` with your locale

restart your computer

Comment: here is my output [i didnt change anything] , and i think it is set to uft-8 already

Comment: `yifanz@yifanz-LIFEBOOK-NH532:~$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_HK.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
`

Comment: did you update locale right now ?

Comment: i get a warning from terminal

Comment: `*** update-locale: Warning: LANGUAGE ("zh_HK:en_US:en") is not compatible with LANG (en_HK.UTF-8). Disabling it.
` and it did not change

Comment: `zh_HK:en_US:en` is not correct code

Comment: which language you use as default ?

Comment: the command i type was `sudo update-locate LANG=en_HK.UTF-8` i hv no idea where does zh_HK:en_US:en come from

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19009/discussion-between-edward-torvalds-and-zhang-yifan).